# Issue with stateful ejb on servlet without @EJB injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I am trying to use a stateful ejb from a servlet, but from what I understood I shouldn't use @EJB injection to do that, and do a lookup instead.

The problem is, so far the only way I managed to achieve this is by using this anotation on the servlet:

```
@EJB(name="LoginRemote", beanInterface = LoginRemote.class)
LoginRemote loginHandler;
```

then the lookup:

```
loginHandler = (LoginRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/LoginRemote");
```

Otherwise I always get a `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` error.

Is this acceptable or should I avoid the @EJB injection completely?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using stateful session beans with servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946348/using-stateful-session-beans-with-servlets)

Comment: Is your EJB `Local` or `Remote' ?

Comment: @Adheep, it's Remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't want to inject an instance into the servlet. Instead, you can use the `@EJB` annotation on the servlet class itself to declare a reference without injecting:

```
@EJB(name="LoginRemote", beanInterface = LoginRemote.class)
public class MyServlet {
```

You can use `@EJBs` if you want to declare multiple references in the same servlet.

(Note that when using the annotation on a field as in your example, the beanInterface parameter is redundant with the field type, but it is required when using the class-level annotation class.)