# (JAVA EE) Method not working without throwing any error

Tags: java, jpa, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm developping an airline management web application with Java EE, EJB & JPA (EclipseLink)

I'm having a trouble when i'm calling a method in the service layer from a servlet : The method don't do what expected without having any error.

The method is AddPassengerToFlight where i am trying to add a passenger to the passengers list that i have in the flight entity with a ManyToMany relationship.

This is the structure of the priject.

This is the Flight and The Passenger Entities whitout the getters and setters:

Flight:

```
public class Flight implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Integer         id;

    @Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
    private Cities          depart;

    @Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
    private Cities          destination;

    private String          prix;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date            date;

    @ManyToMany( cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH } )
    @JoinTable( name = "f_p_join", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "flight_fk" ), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "passenger_fk" ) )
    private List<Passenger> passengers;

    @OneToOne( )
    @JoinColumn( name = "airplane_fk" )
    private Plane           airplane;

    @OneToOne( )
    @JoinColumn( name = "pilot_fk" )
    private Pilot           pilot;
}
```

Passenger:

```
public class Passenger implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Integer      id;

    private String       nom;

    private String       prenom;

    private String       adresse;

    private String       telephone;

    private String       email;

    @Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
    private FlightClass  flightClass;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "passengers" )
    private List<Flight> flights;
}
```

The PassenerService where i have the method :

```
public class PassengerService {

    private static final String CHAMP_FLIGHT_ID    = "flightId";
    private static final String CHAMP_PASSENGER_ID = "passengerId";

    private String              resultat;
    private Map<String, String> erreurs            = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private PassengerDao        passengerDao;
    private FlightDao           flightDao;
    private PilotDao            pilotDao;
    private PlaneDao            planeDao;

    public Map<String, String> getErreurs() {
        return erreurs;
    }

    public String getResultat() {
        return resultat;
    }

    public PassengerService( PassengerDao passengerDao, FlightDao flightDao, PilotDao pilotDao, PlaneDao planeDao ) {
        this.passengerDao = passengerDao;
        this.flightDao = flightDao;
        this.pilotDao = pilotDao;
        this.planeDao = planeDao;
    }

    public Passenger createPassenger( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        //The createPassenger code
    }

    public List<Passenger> getAllPassengers() {
        //The getAllPassengers Code
    }

    public void AddPassengerToFlight( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        FlightService flightService = new FlightService( flightDao, planeDao, pilotDao );

        String passengerId = request.getParameter( CHAMP_PASSENGER_ID );
        String flightId = request.getParameter( CHAMP_FLIGHT_ID );

        Passenger passenger = getPassengerById( passengerId );
        Flight flight = flightService.getFlightById( flightId );

        List<Passenger> pList = flight.getPassengers();
        pList.add( passenger );
        flight.setPassengers( pList );

        passenger.getFlights().add( flight );

    }

    public Passenger getPassengerById( String passengerId ) {
        Passenger passenger = passengerDao.getPassengerById( passengerId );
        return passenger;
    }

    public void removePassenger( Passenger passenger ) {
       //The removePassenger code

    }


}
```

And this is the servlet AddPassengerToFlight

```
@WebServlet( "/AddPassengerToFlight" )
public class AddPassengerToFlight extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String VUE_REDIRECT     = "/airline/PassengerList";

    private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    FlightDao                   flightDao;

    @EJB
    PilotDao                    pilotDao;

    @EJB
    PlaneDao                    planeDao;

    @EJB
    PassengerDao                passengerDao;


    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        FlightService flightService = new FlightService( flightDao, planeDao, pilotDao );
        PassengerService passengerService = new PassengerService( passengerDao, flightDao, pilotDao, planeDao );

        List<Flight> flights = flightService.getAllFlights();
        List<Passenger> passengers = passengerService.getAllPassengers();
        request.setAttribute( "flights", flights );
        request.setAttribute( "passengers", passengers );
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );
    }


    protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        PassengerService passengerService = new PassengerService( passengerDao, flightDao, pilotDao, planeDao );

        passengerService.AddPassengerToFlight( request );
        response.sendRedirect( VUE_REDIRECT );

    }

}
```

And this is the form AddPassengerToFlight (The JSP File)

```
<div class="container">
        <h2>Adding Passenger To Flight</h2>
        <br/><br/>
        <form method="POST" action="AddPassengerToFlight">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Flight :</h4>
                <select name="flightId" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%">
                    <c:forEach items="${flights}" var="flight">
                        <option value="${flight.id}">
                            FROM <c:out value="${flight.depart}" /> TO <c:out value="${flight.destination}" /> AT <c:out value="${flight.date}" />
                        </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Passenger :</h4>
                <select name="passengerId" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%">
                    <c:forEach items="${passengers}" var="passenger">
                        <option value="${passenger.id}"><c:out value="${passenger.nom}" /></option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </div>
```

When i click the button submit of the AddPassengerToFlight im redirected to the PassengerList But Nothing happens between the two entities (Flight and Passenger) and i have no error.

Can anyone figure out what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I Believe that your problem is that your PassengerService Class is a plain JAVA Class (I explain, is not an EJB Service)... thus, when you make the association between Passanger and Flight in that class, there is no JTA transaction running and your entities are in detach mode; so, any changes on them will never be persisted at the database.

You can try this quickly to see if I'm correct... Make your Service an EJB Class and inject the required DAOs through `@EJB` annotation, from the Servlet inject your new EJB and then invoke the method: `AddPassengerToFlight( HttpServletRequest request )` ...

Comment: Hi @Carlitos & thanks for your help. In fact i had a service layer with Stateless EJBs and the method was working i had another problem when i was doing the form validtion i can't pass the result and the errors Map to the servlet by injecting a Stateless EJB so i change the service to the plain JAVA Class but i think you're right i must have an EJB so i change it again to A Stateful EJB so that i can pass the results and the errors Map of the form validation to the servlet. Now the form validation is working but the AddPassengerToFlight Method still doesn't work.

Comment: In the servlet i am instantiating the service by i'm injecting the DAOs and passing them to the constructor  of the servlet (Like i did with the plain JAVA Objects) because i can't inject a statefull EJB in a servlet.

Comment: Why do you need a stateful EJB?

Comment: The form validation did not work with the stateless EJB .. I have to pass a Map that contains the errors of each field to the servlet and to the jsp file so that i can display it and persist the entity if there is no errors, But this Map is not in the Pilot entity so i have to pass a PassengerService instance to the JSP file but i don't get the right result in the Map while using a stateless EJB i think because it does not conserve a state so i'm getting a random values that why i thought of the statefull EJB

Comment: I really don't understand the full design of your application, but be careful when mixin Statefull EJBs with Servlets!! see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946348/using-stateful-session-beans-with-servlets) for more details...